# How do I invoke custom constraint validation as part of the native validation event flow?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

- *The following is based on testing with Chrome 31*
- *TL;DR: How come the code in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/j8yCQ/) works on attempted submit, but doesn't in [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/j8a2s/) on manual invocation? Is there a better way of doing it?*

In answering [a question asking for a way of validating an `<input type="file">` against its `accept` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20524306/check-selected-file-matches-accept-attribute-on-an-input-tag/20998741) (the native behaviour will work with the resulting file dialog to present a filter by default, but it isn't enforced), I wanted to see what options were available to integrate this custom validation into HTML5's scripted [Constraint validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation).

My initial skim-reading of the API led me to overwrite the native [`checkValidity`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-form-checkvalidity) method, in the belief that this would be called by default whenever the browser saw fit to validate the code ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/j8a2s/)):

```
void function enhanceFileInputTypeValidityCheck(){
    var inputPrototype      = document.createElement( 'input' ).constructor.prototype;
    var nativeCheckValidity = inputPrototype.checkValidity;

    // This is my custom validation function
    function validateFileInputType( input ){
        var MIMEtype = new RegExp( input.accept.replace( '*', '.\*' ) );

        return Array.prototype.every.call( input.files, function passesAcceptedFormat( file ){
            return MIMEtype.test( file.type );
        } );
    }

    // My attempt at getting the behaviour to happen 
    inputPrototype.checkValidity = function enhancedCheckValidity(){
        if( this.type === 'file' &&  this.accept && this.files && this.files.length ){
            if( !validateFileInputType( this ) ){
                this.setCustomValidity( 'Please only submit files of type ' + this.accept );

                return false;
            }
        }

        return nativeCheckValidity.apply( this );
    }
}();
```

This effectively enhances `checkValidity` to return `false` when my conditions aren't met, and falls through to native behaviour if they are, but [`setCustomValidity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation#Constraint_API's_element.setCustomValidity()) isn't working as expected: it doesn't throw any exceptions, but doesn't display any error message either. Crucially, my `return false` in `checkValidity` doesn't prevent the form from submitting.

After some fiddling I ended up with this event handler, which along with the code posted above finally achieves the desired aims — namely, preventing submission according to the custom criteria and feeding back to the user ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/j8yCQ/)):

```
$( 'input' ).on( 'change input', function( event ){
    this.checkValidity();
} );
```

I'm mystified as to how this is happening: according to logging the event type, `change` will execute `checkValidity`, but won't display the message; meanwhile attepting to submit the form *does* implement my `setCustomValidity`, but won't log the event type: however the implication is that this is an `input` event, since that's the only other event the handler is listening for — but (and this is where it gets *really* weird), unbinding from `change` (which wasn't working anyway) leaving only `input` as a trigger for my imperative callback [*doesn't prevent submission at all anymore*](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/JJsFr/).

I'm still at a loss for the 'correct' way of binding my custom validation into the native validation flow, since binding to `change` and `event` to trigger expected behaviour when neither of those events is actually taking place just seems far too hacky to be intended usage.

Bonus points for explaining any of the following:

- Why don't I get any feedback from my custom validation `console.log` when invoking `checkValidity` on an empty input?
- Why don't I get any feedback from the `console.log` in the event handler bound to `input` && `change`?
- How come executing code as a callback to the `change` event doesn't trigger `setCustomValidity`?
- What event — if not `input` — is actually triggering my `setCustomValidity`?
- Could I produce the same desired end result without overriding `checkValidity`?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I am aware, the checkValidity method calls the browser's internal validation, rather than being what the browser's internal validation calls. Thus if you override it the browser won't notice or care.

In my experience, all that is necessary to implement custom validity is to bind to the change event and then call setCustomValidity with the right value. For example,

```
myinput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    if ( ! myCustomValidityCheck() )
        this.setCustomValidity( 'Uh oh, that didn\'t work!' );
    else
        this.setCustomValidity( '' );
})
```

[Whimsical JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/lexicality/VK99U/)

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to summarize my experience:

1. The custom validation checks should be performed both on user data input and on form submission button click.
2. You need using both the `setCustomValidity` and the `checkValidity` methods from the HTML5 form validation API.
3. For validation on user data input, you add to the input field element an `input` event listener that invokes `setCustomValidity` on the input field. In the argument of `setCustomValidity` you invoke a suitable check function that returns an empty string if the user input is valid, and a constraint violation message otherwise.
4. For validation on form submission button click, you invoke `checkValidity` on the form element and continue the submission only if this returns `true`.

See also [my answer to a similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22054348/2795909) or [try my example solution](https://oxygen.informatik.tu-cottbus.de/IT/JsFrontendApp/SimpleApp/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for your problems http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/E7VtD/

1. Use change isntead of input event. input event is great, but does not apply to input[type=file].
2. You should not override checkValidity
3. Use setCustomValidity on dom ready + every change
4. use reportValidity, if available, to report errors or mimic reportValditity by clicking on a submit button

Here is a simple method to make setCustomValidity simpler:

```
//setCustomValidity is stupid so we improve by adding setCustomValidityRule
$.fn.setCustomValidityRule = function (type, rule) {
    var testRule = function () {
        //only if it's valid or we have set the message our own
        if ($(this).is(':valid') || $.data(this, 'customErrorType' + type)) {
            var message = rule(this);
            this.setCustomValidity(message);
            if (message) {
                $.data(this, 'customErrorType' + type, message)
            } else {
                $.removeData(this, 'customErrorType' + type);
            }
        }
    };
    return this
    //invoke initially
    .each(testRule)
    //and on every change
    .on('customchange.customerror' + type + ' change.customerror' + type, testRule);
};
```

And here is a method to make reportValidity work in current browsers:

```
$.fn.reportValidity = function () {
    return this.each(function () {
        var form;
        if (this.reportValidity) {
            this.reportValidity();
        } else {
            form = $($.prop(this, 'form')).add(this).filter('form');
            //checkvalidity is obtrusive sometimes so we use :invalid
            if($(':invalid', form).length){
            $('<input type="submit" />')
                .css({
                    position: 'absolute',
                    left: '-99999px'
                })
                .appendTo(form)
                .click()
                .remove();
            }
        }
    });
};
```