# File field "accept" attribute not working properly when drag and drop file into it

Tags: html, forms, form-fields

I have file field like this:

```
<input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">
```

it works correctly when i click and choose file but it accept all type of files when i drag and drop files into it.

Any idea ?

FYI : i have fixed this issue by adding a server side validation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *accept* parameter is used to let the browser know it should ask the OS for a *file selector dialog* which would accept only these type of files.

So this is actually an OS feature.

Now, when you drag&drop a file, the browser doesn't require to open a *file selector dialog*, so this attribute is not used.

But you can still listen to the change event and do your checking there.

```js
inp.onchange = function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var file = this.files[0];
  if(file.type.indexOf('image/') !== 0) {
    this.value = null;
    console.log("invalid");
  }
  else {
    console.log('valid file');
  }
}
```

```html
Drop a file on this input. <br>
<input type="file" accepts="image/*" id="inp">
```

**Important notes**

- `accepts`, just like MIME Type checking is only done against the file extension, i.e really easily spoofable, you can try a [magic-number check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29672957/3702797), but you should anyway always check from the server.
- The above snippet will work only if your user uploaded a single file. I don't know what you want to do in case they upload a folder or multiple files, but beware that they'll be able to do it, and thus that you will have to handle these cases.

Comment: for me "file.type" always comming as empty string like this..
file.type = ""

Comment: @Cegone You mean even from the snippet in the answer? What browser/OS?

Comment: Currently i'm using this 
<ngx-file-drop browseBtnClassName="linkButton" accept="xlsx" (onFileDrop)="fileDropped($event)">

eventhough the accept is also not working
and chrome browser, Windows 7

Comment: For me, it's not working in windows machine. But working fine in Ubuntu Os

Answer (score 5):

The above answer does not really answer the question, it does not use the accept value, it just validates images. If the accept value would be something like 'text/plain' it will fail.

you can use this verify function to validate the file-type on the accept string:

```
verifyAccept = function( file-type, accept ) {
    var type-regex = new RegExp( accept.replace( /\*/g, '.\*' ).replace( /\,/g, '|' ) );
    return type-regex.test( file-type );
}
```

mentioned here: [Check selected file matches accept attribute on an <input> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20524306/check-selected-file-matches-accept-attribute-on-an-input-tag/59709534#59709534)

Answer (score 0):

You might consider a library (or copying its code) such as [attr-accept](https://github.com/react-dropzone/attr-accept) to validate that the file dropped matches your `accept="..."` as close to the browser's native validation as possible.

For example: when you click on "Choose File" rather than dropping, it will validate based on `accept="image/*,application/pdf"`).